# Meaning of no more likely

Tags: meaning, syntactic-analysis, negation, comparatives

A is no more likely than B. Does this mean

1. A is either as likely or less likely than B.
2. A and B occur with the same likelihood.

Comment: 'A is no more likely than B' -> 'A is not > B' -> 'A <= B'. Your '1' is correct. '2' is include as part of your '1'

Answer (score 5):

A different way of phrasing "A is no more likely than B" would be "A is equally or less likely to occur than B".

The above is a logical inversion, and language isn't always as logical as we'd like it to be. From personal experience, people seem to mostly intend to say that A and B are equally likely to happen.

Either of your options is right. A is technically the most correct translation, while B will mostly be what people mean by it.